# Matching thousands of data takes too much time with Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, opendatasoft

I receive every day a report with some values and I have to match postal codes from countries all over the world to get the right region. Then I upload the result in my Django app.
Here's a look at my report:

| Order Number | Date | City | Postal code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 930276 | 27/09/2022 | Madrid | cp: 28033 |
| 929670 | 27/09/2022 | Lisboa | cp: 1600-812 |

I have thousands of rows like this. The objective is to retrieve the region in ISO 3166-2 format. To help me, I accessed the following page [Geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) and downloaded all the countries' information (example: "FR.txt", "ES.txt"...)
Because this is a huge `txt` file, I chose to store it on a S3 Server.
Here is what I tried:

```
def access_scaleway(region_name, endpoint_url, access_key, secret_key):
    """ Accessing Scaleway Bucket """

    scaleway = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region_name, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

    return scaleway

def get_region_code_accessing_scaleway(countries, regions):
    ''' Retrieves the region code from the region name. '''

    list_countries = countries
    list_regions = regions
    list_regions_codes = []
    scaleway_session = access_scaleway(region_name=settings.SCALEWAY_S3_REGION_NAME,
                                       endpoint_url=settings.SCALEWAY_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
                                       access_key=settings.SCALEWAY_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                       secret_key=settings.SCALEWAY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    for country, region in zip(list_countries, list_regions):
        try:
            obj = scaleway_session.get_object(Bucket=settings.SCALEWAY_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, Key=f'countries/{country}.txt')
            df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), sep='\t', header=None)
            df.columns = ['country code', 'postal code', 'place name', 'admin name1', 'admin code1', 'admin name2', 'admin code2', 'admin name3', 'admin code3', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'accuracy']
            df['postal code'] = df['postal code'].astype(str)
            df['postal code'] = df['postal code'].str.zfill(5)
            # Removing all spaces and special characters
            postal_code = re.sub("[^0-9^-]", '', region).strip()
            region_code = country + "-" + df[df['postal code'] == postal_code]['admin code1'].values[0]
            list_regions_codes.append(region_code)

        except AttributeError:
            list_regions_codes.append(None)
        except ValueError:
            list_regions_codes.append(None)


    return list_regions_codes
```

But it is way too long. For a simple report of 1000 rows, it takes like 30 min.

My second try was to go with the `OpenDataSoft` public API. Here is what I tried:

```
def fetch_data(url, params, headers=None):
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    return response

def get_region_code_accessing_scaleway(countries, regions):
    ''' Retrieves the region code from the region name. '''

    list_countries = countries
    list_regions = regions
    list_regions_codes = []

    for country, region in zip(list_countries, list_regions):
        try:
            #Get response from API
            postal_code = re.sub("[^0-9^-]", '', region).strip()
            response = fetch_data(
                url="https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/v2/catalog/datasets/geonames-postal-code%40public/records?",
                params="select=country_code%2C%20postal_code%2C%20admin_code1&where=country_code%3D%22" + country + "%22%20and%20postal_code%3D%22" + postal_code + "%22")

            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                if len(data['records']) > 0:
                    list_regions_codes.append(country + "-" + data['records'][0]['record']['fields']['admin_code1'])
                else:
                    list_regions_codes.append(None)

            else:
                print('Error:" + response.status_code')
                list_regions_codes.append(None)
```

But once again, it takes like forever to get matching values.
The last thing I tried was to go with `pgeocode` but it was also too long.
I don't understand why it is so long because the desired output is this one:

| Order Number | Date | City | Postal code | Region code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 930276 | 27/09/2022 | Madrid | cp: 28033 | ES-MD |
| 929670 | 27/09/2022 | Lisboa | cp: 1600-812 | PT-08 |

Do you have any idea to speed up the process?

Comment: Is this solution still slow for you if you test it with the files locally instead of on Scaleway?  My first thought is that it's taking a long time because you may be reading the same object from your S3 bucket multiple times.  It might be more efficient to load the all regions zip file from Geonames (~16MB compressed) once, and just do all of your queries off of that one.

Comment: Hi @rnorris, sorry for the delayed answer. This was an excellent suggestion. So I tried to load the zip file at the beginning of the function and matched the data afterwards. It's a lot quicker. Thank you very much